# How to scrape (ideally with python) the very first image that appears on Google Search ("All", not images)?

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, google-search

I am using Edge browser, and when I type in Google search (not Google images, just "All") the stock exchange name + ticker (e.g. "NASDAQ: AAPL", "NASDAQ: TSLA", etc.) I get the companies logo at the left top. Is there a way to automate such process and scrape the images?
Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.